# Add new customer action to Magento customer grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to add a custom action to the Customer Grid page in Magento.

I have two modules: One is called Manager which is a customer service Call Log that has a list of reasons for customer calls ie "general info", "order query", "hoax call". All the reasons are stored in a database. The 'Manager' module is similar to how assigning customers to groups works.

The second module is called Customergrid which extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid

Here is where I have added an option in the dropdown menu called "Add to Call Log". I would like this to work in a similar way to how adding a customer to a 'group' would work. If I select a customer from the grid list and select "Add to Call Log" I then need to select from another dropdown (exactly like adding to customer group) a "reason" and click save.

The issue:

I need to find a way to display the list of reasons in the dropdown list.

Here is my code for Grid.php from customergrid module:

```
<?php
class Module_Customergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));
        /*$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
            'index'     => 'firstname'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
            'index'     => 'lastname'
        ));*/
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));

        $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('group', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'width'     =>  '100',
            'index'     =>  'group_id',
            'type'      =>  'options',
            'options'   =>  $groups,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ZIP'),
            'width'     => '90',
            'index'     => 'billing_postcode',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_country_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Country'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'country',
            'index'     => 'billing_country_id',
        ));

       $this->addColumn('billing_region', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('State/Province'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_region',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_since', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Since'),
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'gmtoffset' => true
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('website_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Website'),
                'align'     => 'center',
                'width'     => '80px',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteOptionHash(true),
                'index'     => 'website_id',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('customer');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
             'confirm'  => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_subscribe', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Subscribe to Newsletter'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSubscribe')
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_unsubscribe', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Unsubscribe from Newsletter'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massUnsubscribe')
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('manager_grid', array(
             'label'        => Mage::helper('manager')->__('Add to call log'),
             'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignGroup'),
             'additional'   => array(
                'visibility'    => array(
                     'name'     => 'reason',
                     'type'     => 'select',
                     'class'    => 'required-entry',
                     'label'    => Mage::helper('manager')->__('Reason'),
                     'values'   => $data
                 )
            )
        ));        

        $groups = $this->helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();
        array_unshift($groups, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('assign_group', array(
             'label'        => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Assign a Customer Group'),
             'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignGroup'),
             'additional'   => array(
                'visibility'    => array(
                     'name'     => 'group',
                     'type'     => 'select',
                     'class'    => 'required-entry',
                     'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
                     'values'   => $groups
                 )
            )
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=> true));
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
    }


}
```

Can anyone tell me if I am going about this in the correct way as I am unable to display the 'reasons' list in the second dropdown field. I am new to customising Magento admin so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

If I try to add options to the array I get an empty screen:

```
$collection = $this->helper('manager')->getCollection()->toOptionArray();
array_unshift($manager, array('label'=> '','value'=>''));
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('manager', array(
     'label'        => Mage::helper('manager')->__('Add to call log'),
     'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignManager'),
     'additional'   => array(
        'visibility'    => array(
             'name'     => 'manager',
             'type'     => 'select',
             'class'    => 'required-entry',
             'label'    => Mage::helper('manager')->__('Reason'),
             'values'   => $manager
         )
    )
));
```

I can't figure out why!!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something good, just one thing for the additionnal dropdown : 'values'   => $data. Data is undefined.

Look at group to see how it works to serialize option to enable this second dropdown

```
$groups = $this->helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();
    array_unshift($groups, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
```

You need something similar to get option in an array here.

Comment: This exactly what I am having trouble with... Thanks for letting me know that I am close...

Comment: log the $groups variable, you'll see the structure and you'll be able to do the same, basically it's something like `$collection = Model->getCollection()->filters/select/etc; $collection = $collection->toOptionArray(); array_unshift($collection,array('label'=>'','value'=>''));` As I don't know your model structure I can't be more precise.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, if you are able to assist slightly further I'd be very grateful. This is what I have used as the basis of my module http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid?facebook=1

Comment: Sorry, I have to much work to do some extra (even if you offer to pay for it). Maybe give us more info about the module you're using I may find the solution or someone else may help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time. From the info you have posted I hold be able to solve this.